# Mongodb aggregation - geoNear and text search in joined collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a tricky query that hits my MongoDB know-how. Here the simplified szenario.

We have a collection `Restaurant` and a collection `Subsidary`.
They look roughly like this (simplified - using mongoose):

```
const restaurantSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    categories: { type: [String], required: true },
...
})


const subsidarySchema = new Schema(
  {
    restaurant: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Restaurant' },
    location: {
      type: { type: String, enum: ['Point'], required: true },
      coordinates: { type: [Number], required: true },
    },
...
})
```

#### What is required:

- Always: Find restaurants that have a subsidary within 3.5 KM radius and sort by distance.
- Sometimes filter those restaurants also by a string that should fuzy-match the Restaurant name.
- Apply further filters and pagination (e.g. filter by categories, ...)

I'm trying to tackle this with a mongodb aggregation. The problem:
The aggregation pipeline stages `geoNear` and `text` require each to be first in the pipeline - which means they exclude each other.

#### Here my thought so far:

1. Start aggregation with subsidary, `$geoNear` stage first. This cuts away already all restaurants outside the 3.5 KM.
2. `$group` the subsidaries by restaurant and keep the minimal distance value per cluster.
3. `$lookup` to get the matchin restaurant for each cluster. Maybe `$unwind` here.
4. **???** Here the text/search match should be, fuzy-matching the restaurants' name. **???**
5. `$match` for other values (category, openingHours, ...)
6. `$sort` and `$limit` and `$skip` for sorting andd pagination.

Here the same as illustration.

[image: MongoDB Aggregation Stages]

#### Question

- Does this approach make sense? What would be a possible way to implement stage 4?
- I was searching a lot but there seems no way to use something like `{ $match: { $text: { $search: req.query.name } } }` as a 4th stage.
- An alternative would be to run a second query before that just handles the text search and then build an intersection. This could lead to a massive amount of restaurant IDs being passed in that stage. Is that something mongodb could handle?

I'm very thankful for your comments!

Comment: $text probably doesn't fuzzy search the way you want.  For example, if the name in the document is "Blueberry Barn", search for "blueberries" and "bARN" will match, but searches for "Blue", "berry", and "bar" will not.

Comment: Fair point! But I could probably use the new `$search` stage - that is apparently only available on Atlas. https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/search

Answer (score 1):

Some ways around the requirement that both text search and geo query must be the first stage:

- Use text search as the first stage, then manually calculate the distance using $set/$expr in a subsequent stage.
- Use geo query as the first stage, then perform text filtering in your application (allowing you also to use any text matching/similarity algorithm you like).

Comment: Any suggestions how to perform text search in my app? Is there a good library that would make sense to use in this case? Would e.g. lunrjs be a good choice?

Comment: This would also cause the problem that I have to handle pagination myself. But Sorting and Filtering should still be possible to keep in the aggregation. right?